# Creating only new rows in a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move data and transform it using a trigger, into another table. 
I have the table set up and this development code:

```
DELIMITER//

CREATE TRIGGER move_data AFTER 
INSERT ON schema.old_table 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


DECLARE num_id_before, num_id_after INT;
SET num_id_before = (select count(id) FROM schema.old_table);
SET num_id_after = (num_id_before - 7);

INSERT INTO schema.new_table (name, street_address, 
            street_address_line_2, city, state, zip, country, fr_dob)

SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 0 THEN element_value end) AS name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 1 THEN element_value end) AS street_address, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 2 THEN element_value end) AS street_address_line_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 3 THEN element_value end) AS city, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 4 THEN element_value end) AS state,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 5 THEN element_value end) AS zip,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 6 THEN element_value end) AS country,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 7 THEN element_value end) AS dob

FROM schema.old_table 
LIMIT num_id_after, num_id_before 
GROUP BY group_id

END //
DELIMITER;
```

It currently works without the:

```
DECLARE num_id_before, num_id_after INT;
SET num_id_before = (select count(id) FROM schema.old_table);
SET num_id_after = (num_id_before - 7);
```

and:

```
LIMIT num_id_after, num_id_before
```

with those pieces of code added, I get this error:

```
 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'num_id_after, num_id_before GROUP BY group_id END' at line 22
```

~EDIT: I know that this is generic error for basically "something isn't right", but it might help diagnose, I am fairly new to mysql

The only problem is that it copies all the previous data every time it runs instead of just newly added rows. Currently the old table sets data as each value is a separate row in a group. I need it to be in a new table with each group in a single row.

Can anyone help with this? Feel free to ask for more info

Comment: limit should be used in the end of query

Comment: This isn't "generic". This pinpoints exactly where the error occurs (at or immediately to the left of the word 'num_id_after')!

Comment: I get this if I do that:  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'num_id_after, num_id_before END' at line 23

Answer (score 1):

As @M Khalid Junaid comments, change the order of your clauses:

```
FROM schema.old_table 
GROUP BY group_id
LIMIT num_id_after, num_id_before;

END //
```

GROUP BY clause is always before LIMIT clause. It also needs a `;` to end the query.

Comment: As I replied to his answer, it just gives me a slightly different error return.

Comment: Add a `;` to end the query, :D, updated in the answer

Comment: for some reason, what I need to get it to work correctly breaks the application code somehow when I make the trigger. I am not sure how this is happening as it is an "after insert" trigger. The code works correctly otherwise. It breaks when I add the limit.